# Does Stack Overflow have checks in place to prevent people from 'gaming' the badge system?

Tags: discussion, badges, upvotes, electorate-badge

For example, the electorate badge has the following requirement:

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Is there any reason (besides ethics and wasting time, arguably) that I shouldn't upvote the next 600 questions I find?

Comment: Yes, downvoting would likely have a more beneficial effect

Comment: While I would absolutely discourage the behavior you describe and instead vote up or down as you see fit (more beneficial for everyone that way), a single vote on any question or answer isn’t moving the needle *all* that much that anybody would consider it “gaming” the system. The end result for you also doesn’t make much material difference except adding 1 to the badge count below your name.

Comment: Some of them are more impressive than others. Like the [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) silver bagde is more impressive than the gold [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic).

Comment: Many, many such checks in place, but we won't tell you all of them, lest you game around those checks. :-)

Comment: One check, I suppose, is that the gold badge means nothing. Whether you get it in few weeks or few months (voting on few questions a day) makes no difference. Nor does *not* getting it. It's just a number on the profile page and it has no impact on anything.

Comment: You will be amazed by the fact that if you actually commit to such fraudulent voting, that you may be caught by either software or... eh... fleshware. I mean people. Whatever you do, it is scrutinised in some way.

Comment: Whether or not you care about them doesn't change the fact that they do occasionally attract abuse by people who do.

Comment: And if you don't care, the Care Bears will come for you.

Answer (score 14):

#### Yes, this is considered fraudulent voting.  Profiles are deleted and/or votes reversed when people are caught.

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, [animuson described an incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362059/165261) in which a user who had attempted to cheat in this manner had their votes reversed.  They also noted that normally, users attempting to cheat these badges simply have their profiles deleted.  I'm not sure why this user was an exception (maybe they had also contributed useful content that staff didn't want to remove?), but the post in general implies that users caught doing this are regularly punished.

Comment: "*I'm not sure why this user was an exception*" Heh, when it comes to petty norm violations (like voting on questions with little rhyme or reason to earn a badge), I could see "got a good night's sleep" as a valid reason for such charity from a moderator.

Comment: Got a good night's sleep is so rare that it should be worth a gold badge unto itself. Maybe even a platinum badge. [But then again...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqomZQMZQCQ),